# Injector = undefined in Production Environment

Tags: angular

The code works fine when I run wuth ng serve.
In production environement it throws an exception in this part

```
constructor(@Inject(Injector) injector: Injector, @Inject(AuthService) private authService: AuthService ) {
    this.injector = injector;
  }
```

I debug the code and I found that injector and authService are undefined. Roughly speaking it cannot inject a new instance of Injector class neither for AuthService

Did I miss something?

in app.module I call TorkenInterceptor like this.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FullLayoutComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    StoreModule.forRoot(fromRoot.reducer.reducers),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument(),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([])
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: fromShared.services.TokenInterceptorService,
      multi: true,
    },
    AuthService,
    AuthGuard,
    ......
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

TokenInterceptor class

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  // private authService: AuthService;
  injector: Injector
  constructor(@Inject(Injector) injector: Injector, @Inject(AuthService) private authService: AuthService ) {
    this.injector = injector;
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('INTERCETP');
      if (this.getAuthService().isAuthenticated()) {
          request = request.clone({
              setHeaders: {
                  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.getAuthService().getToken()
              }
          });
      }
      return next.handle(request);
  }

  getAuthService(): AuthService {
      if (typeof this.authService === 'undefined') {
          this.authService = this.injector.get(AuthService);
      }
      return this.authService;
  }
}
```

Environment :

**OS :** Docker

**Angular Version :** 7.2.4

**NG command  :** RUN npm run ng build -- --prod --output-path=dist --optimization=false

[image]

Comment: In fact I have the problems in every module, All injected services are undefined